# Reminiscence, sleuthing

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, sentence-choice

Reminiscence means recollecting past events and sleuthing means a detective solving mystery. When writing or talking, can it be delivered like this
I met a very old friend, we were reminiscing,or reminiscing the past.
They have appointed a sleuthing detective.

Comment: [A sleuth](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sleuth) is another word for a detective, so it would be tautology to speak of 'a sleuthing detective'.

Answer (score 1):

*Reminiscing* implies going over the past, so you shouldn't say *reminiscing the past*.

There may be uses for *sleuthing*, but *sleuthing detective* is too wordy. *Sleuth* means a detective.

[Merriam-Webster *sleuth*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sleuth)
noun  :detective
intransitive verb : to act as a detective : search for information
transitive verb : to search for and discover